# Assembly/ABI: Caller Responsibility for Large Return Types

Tags: windows, assembly, 64-bit, calling-convention

My assembly skills are rather poor, but I've been trying to understand assembly a little better to improve my understanding of profiling sessions and how optimizing compilers work.

One of the things that I never stopped to really think about at the machine level when studying 64-bit calling conventions for Windows is that given something like this:

```
struct BigUdt
{
    double buf[16]; // exceeds 64 bits
};
struct BigUdt create_big_udt();
```

... if I understood the documentation properly, `create_big_udt` would normally allocate the memory for `struct BigUdt` (I'm assuming on the stack) and return the address to its memory in `rax`.

So my question, from an assembly standpoint, is this: *where does that leave the caller as far as responsibilities go?* I'm assuming someone is left with the responsibility of adding `sizeof(BidUdt)` back to `rsp` at some point. Also would 64-bit stack alignment become a concern here for types whose sizes aren't a multiple of 64-bits, or would that be covered by `struct BigUdt's` padding?

Phew, I hope that's a reasonable question. I find these ABI contracts between caller and callee with calling conventions quite intimidating and one of the hardest parts of learning assembly so far.

Comment: an easy thing to do is to construct simple tests, assemble and disassemble them to see what a compiler that conforms to that abi does

Comment: Been doing that kind of reverse engineering thing a lot to try to figure these calling conventions out! One of the things I find perplexing for this kind of case above is that it seems, if I understand the disassembly properly,  that calling such a function leaves `rsp` untouched/restored by the time we return from the caller. So it doesn't seem like it leaves the responsibility to the callee necessarily to add back to `rsp`, but perhaps it does need to use that data immediately before overwriting it in the stack. How optimizers deal with this makes my brain want to explode.

Comment: ahh you are talking about the caller not callee.  Just a guess, I would assume the callee sets it up on the stack and restores the stack leaving it hanging in the wind, the caller IF it actually wants that value will have a variable that variable will be local or global and depending will be allocated somewhere.  If big enough the assigment ret=function() would generate a memcpy().  but I have not tried this to confirm....

Comment: Many thanks -- that "hanging in the wind" analogy seems to match what I'm seeing when I check out the disassembly of compilers. That's also a bit more comforting -- I thought there was a potential for disaster there if the caller forgot to do something with `rsp` afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7572ztz4.aspx) is quite clear:

> Otherwise, the caller assumes the responsibility of allocating memory
>   and passing a pointer for the return value as the first argument.
>   Subsequent arguments are then shifted one argument to the right. The
>   same pointer must be returned by the callee in RAX.

So basically `foo bar(...)` gets turned into `foo* bar(foo* retval, ...)`. The pointer may point to wherever the caller wants the result (typically it will be the address of a local variable in the caller's stack frame) which is of course unaffected by the stack operations involved in the call, and is always valid memory, stack or otherwise. It's never "hanging in the wind" (if I understood the term properly), since that would indeed be a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Ooh, I missed that part about the caller allocating the memory and pointing to it in `RCX`! Thanks, that clears up a lot about some of the things I was confused about in the disassembly I was looking at.